# Prove that the value of $(4\cos^2 9-1)(4\cos^2 27 -1)(4\cos^2 81-1)(4\cos^2 243-1)$ is 1

Tags: trigonometry, proof-writing

*all angles are in degrees*

I have done the necessary calculations. I won’t list them here, but this what my final result was $$(3-4\sin^2 18)(3-4\sin^254)$$

How do I get the value of 1 from this, other than actually substituting the values of $\sin 18$ and $\sin 54$?

Comment: Check please your problem. It's not true.

Comment: Assuming that the final expression is correct, note that $(3 - 4 \sin^2 18) = \dfrac{(3 \sin 18 - 4 \sin^3 18)}{\sin 18} = \dfrac{\sin 54}{\sin 18}$. Similarly the other term gives $\dfrac{\sin 162}{\sin 54} = \dfrac{\sin 18}{\sin 54}$. Multiplying them gives you your answer.

Comment: @Aditya Because I checked it. Check also you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use $2\sin^2 a=1-\cos 2a$,$$(3-4\sin^2 18)(3-4\sin^254)
=(1+2\cos36 )(1-2\cos72)
$$

Note that $2\cos36$ and $-2\cos72$ are the roots of $f(x)=x^2-x-1$. Thus,
$$(3-4\sin^2 18)(3-4\sin^254) =f(-1)=1$$

Answer (score 1):

I think, it means $$(4\cos^2 9^{\circ}-1)(4\cos^2 27^{\circ} -1)(4\cos^281^{\circ}-1)(4\cos^2 243^{\circ}-1)=1.$$ 
Indeed, $$(4\cos^2 9^{\circ}-1)(4\cos^2 27^{\circ} -1)(4\cos^281^{\circ}-1)(4\cos^2 243^{\circ}-1)=$$
$$=(2\cos18^{\circ}+1)(2\cos54^{\circ} +1)(1-2\cos18^{\circ})(1-2\cos54^{\circ})=$$
$$=(1-4\cos^218^{\circ})(1-4\cos^254^{\circ})=(2\cos36^{\circ}+1)(2\cos108^{\circ}+1)=$$
$$=\left(\frac{1+\sqrt5}{2}+1\right)\left(-\frac{\sqrt5-1}{2}+1\right)=1.$$

Comment: Yes, it was typo, I am sorry. I thought you meant the question was inherently wrong. Fixed it though

Answer (score 1):

As commented by sudeep,

$$4\cos^2x-1=4(1-\sin^2x)-1=\dfrac{\sin3x}{\sin x}$$  for $\sin x\ne0$

$$\prod_{r=1}^4(4\cos^2({3^{r+1}}^\circ)-1)=\dfrac{\sin{3^3}^\circ}{\sin{3^2}^\circ}\cdot\dfrac{\sin{3^4}^\circ}{\sin{3^3}^\circ}\cdot\dfrac{\sin{3^5}^\circ}{\sin{3^4}^\circ}\cdot\dfrac{\sin{3^6}^\circ}{\sin{3^5}^\circ}=\dfrac{\sin729^\circ}{\sin9^\circ}$$

Now $729^\circ=2\cdot360^\circ+9^\circ$